# Oracle UCM Archiver looks like it is not exporting documents

Tags: oracle-ucm

We have an Archiver setup which has been running for a long time and in the last few months has started acting up, UCM version 10gR3. New IT staff have definitely done things to some of the files it needs in order to run properly and I think they at least think they restored backups of the files they deleted.

The archive in question is supposed to run every 2 weeks but it is configured in automation mode right now, so I think it runs every 5 minutes or otherwise fairly often. Either way, if you preview the query the documents to be exported it is a fairly big list but the most recent run of the Archive, 0 records are exported. The admin log on the server has not been updated since 10/2 and honestly not all of the archives are mentioned in the different logs before that, and it is definitely spottier than every 2 weeks.

My question is what are the typical culprits for this and how can I check it?  The automated archive that is failing has a folder on the file system which only contains archive.hda and exports.hda.  The one that most recently succeded with a log I can view from the admin menu has archive.hda, collection.hda, collection.mrk, and exports.hda.  Maybe there's another file somewhere else.  But it makes no sense to me that this could tell me in a preview I have over 200 documents waiting to be archived but none get archived when it runs.